# command preceded by "\"in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

Whats the difference between commands:-

1. ls
2. \ls

So if i write

```
$ls
or 
$\ls
```

Whats the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The backslash will force the `ls` command to be used [without any aliasing](http://www-zeuthen.desy.de/dv/documentation/unixguide/chapter2.html).

Comment: pls tell a bit about aliasing. Whats aliasing actually?

Comment: An explanation of aliasing may warrant a new question, but here are some useful aliases http://superuser.com/questions/7083/useful-command-line-aliases and the Wikipedia explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29

Comment: @Shadyabhi An alias is a short string that has been defined as a convenient short-cut for a longer command. E.g., `ls` may normally be an alias for `ls --color`, which is generally more useful than `ls`'s normal behaviour. The MAN page documents the `alias` command: http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html

Comment: thanx for pointing out that "ls --color" thing. I was just about that thing too.. Thanx.. nicely put.

Answer (score 2):

In general, backslash suppresses expansion, except, confusingly, where it does C-like escaping of control characters.

In the first part of your question, sblair is right, the backslash suppresses aliasing, or alias expansion..

In the second part, the backslash suppresses dollar-expansion: `$ls` expands to the current value of the `ls` shell variable, whilst `$\ls` is not expanded.  So if `ls` is not `set` to anything, `echo $ls; echo $\ls` will print a blank line (the contents of $ls) followed by `$ls` on the next line.

Comment: thanx. short and precise.